# How to use old wireless headset board to drive an amplifier

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, power-amplifier, headphones

I have an old wireless headset which I took apart and used its circuit board to drive a 2x15W TDA7297 amplifier.

The problem is, the amplifier sounds at least twice as quiet though Bluetooth than it sounds if I connect the amp directly to my phone using a 3.5mm mini jack cable (both at 50% volume).

I suppose that it has to do with the fact that the board is designed to drive 32Ω headphones instead of an amplifier but I don't know for sure. I am also a little worried that I might be damaging it by using it that way:

[image]

Could you help identify the problem in this design?

Comment: This question requires a schematic of what you did including power rail details.

Comment: @Andyaka They're powered by different batteries since the headset board is operating at 3.7V while the amplifier requires 12V and I don't want to form any nasty ground loops